# Three.js quality of rendering

Tags: three.js

I am new to three.js and 3D modeling. I managed to load my gltf model and show it in the browser using three.js, see this picture:

[image]
When I turn the cube around I notice that the quality of rendering the edges is not very high (in the picture the edge in the back looks 'zigzag'). Can I improve this somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The artefact on edges is called [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing)

set antialias to true in WebGLRenderer

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.antialias

i.e.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit too advanced at this point, but if you later want to use [post-effects](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-use-post-processing), you can't use antialias:true on the renderer to  improve edges. But this can be achieved using something called [FXAA](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_fxaa.html) as a post effect. This can also be used if you disable antialias for performance reason. On older mobiles, or with complex scenes it can sometimes be better to render without antialiasing and use the post effect instead. Not as good, but better than nothing.